# What to do with error "Requested action failed to validate. Please review the Boto exceptions below for more details."?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, aws-cloudformation

I'm attempting to create some mock tests for some in-house AWS scripts. Upon creating the boto3 resource and attempting to validate a non-existent stack, I get the following error when I run my python script:

"The requested action failed to validate. Please review the Boto exceptions below for more details."

This would be great except....there is no "Boto exceptions below" like the error mentions, just the command prompt. What does this mean?

Here is some example code:

```
def function():
    resource = boto3.resource('cloudformation')
    verify_stack(resource, 'MockStack')

def verify_stack(session, stackName):
      try:
          stack = session.meta.client.describe_stacks(StackName=stack_name)

      except:
          return {}

      else:
          return stack
```

Just for reference, the stack "MockStack" doesn't exist, and I'm testing to make sure of this. A part of me thinks the error I'm getting is telling me that the stack doesn't exist, which would be correct. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my issue. It was a ClientError that I caught by wrapping the `verify_stack` function in a try/except statement. Here is the correct code:

```
try:
    session = boto3.Session()
    resource = session.resource('cloudformation')

    sqs_template = {
        "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
        "Resources": {
            "QueueGroup": {

            "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue",
            "Properties": {
                "QueueName": "my-queue",
                "VisibilityTimeout": 60,
            }
            },
        },
    }

    sqs_template_json = json.dumps(sqs_template)

    resource.create_stack(
        StackName="mock_stack",
        TemplateBody=sqs_template_json,
    )

    response = resource.verify_stack(resource, 'mock_stack')

    print  response

except ClientError as error:
    print error.message
```